# Integrate negative order square root

Tags: definite-integrals

I've been trying to solve this integral and can't figure out where to start from:
$$
\int\limits _0^1 r\sqrt{\dfrac{4r^2}{(r^2+\varepsilon^2)^2}+1} \textrm{  d}r
$$ where $0<\varepsilon<1$.

Comment: Is $\varepsilon$ supposed to be small?  If so you can expand the square root in a power series.  $u=r^2$ looks like a bit of a simplification.

Comment: My bad, epsilon is bounded between 0 and 1

Comment: I fed this to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*sqrt(4x%5E2%2F(x%5E2%2Ba%5E2)%5E2%2B1)+from+0+to+1) without success

Comment: The substitution $u=r^2+\epsilon^2$ immediately suggests itself, but is not enough on its own. Where did this integral come from? Do you have reasons to suspect it has a closed form?

Comment: i would substitute $$t=\sqrt{\frac{4r^2}{(r^2+\epsilon^2)^2+1}}$$

Comment: According to Maple, it has a closed form, which is ... quite long.

Comment: maybe we can simplify the output

Comment: Here is the output (a=$\epsilon$) : $-\ln(2)-\ln(a^2+1)+\ln(3+a^2+\sqrt{5+2a^2+a^4})-a\arctan\left(\dfrac{(\sqrt{5+2a^2+a^4}-a^2+1)a}{a^2\sqrt{5+2a^2+a^4}+a^2-1}\right)-(1/2)a^2+(1/2)\sqrt{5+2a^2+a^4}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  -- your comment suggesting the substitution uses a radical expression that has a significant difference with the posted radical expression [Note: the +1 term placement].  Was this done on purpose?

Comment: I fed the integral into Mathematica and it produced an answer after about 15 to 20 seconds of processing (on MacBook Pro 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7).  The answer is similar to what @nicomezi posted in his comment.  I have not bothered to make sure they were identical or not, could be though.